# Autostart python script and see its output on the terminal

Tags: python, bash, cron

Is there any way that i can auto run a python script at boot and see its output on the terminal other than editing the .bashrc file ?

I tried using crontab job and putting myscript in /etc/init.d/ directory but these two methods require a log file to see the output and that's not what i want.

Comment: is this a long running script? or just a quick thing to process during startup

Comment: it's a quick simple script that prints something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually, .bashrc won't work to start something on boot. You might try running stuff on /etc/rc.local, that will print output to what you see during boot time. But in order to work "right" your script has to either finish or it has to go into the background. If it hangs forever without letting execution continue, boot sequence won't finish.

Addendum:
Real question was related to user login time, not boot time. The answer is to use ~/.profile.

Comment: Also, I would recommend to use syslog module to send output to syslog. That's way more elegant.

Comment: /etc/rc.local also doesn't print stuff to the terminal

Comment: It does print stuff on the terminal. During boot time you see something about "My IP is blah blah"? That's on rc.local.

Comment: no actually i don't see that, i log in via putty

Comment: putty? ssh? That's certainly _not_ boot time. That's more like _user login time_. I think you have to try in one of these: ~/.bashrc, ~/.profile